# Lua C API: what's the difference between lua_gettop() and -1?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I don't really understand stack exactly.

```
lua_gettop()
```

> Returns the index of the top element in the stack. Because indices
>   start at 1, this result is equal to the number of elements in the
>   stack (and so 0 means an empty stack).

so what's the difference between it and -1?

```
lua_getglobal(L,"Foo");
if( lua_isfunction(L,lua_gettop(L)) ) {

lua_getglobal(L,"Foo");
if( lua_isfunction(L,-1) ) {
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can imagine the stack as growing from the bottom, with the bottom (i.e., the first pushed) element having index 1, then you push another element (index 2), then another one (index 3), etc.. So you have this situation:

```
+-----------------------+
| element with index 6  | <-- top ("relative" index -1)
+-----------------------+
| element with index 5  | <-- -2
+-----------------------+
| element with index 4  | <-- -3
+-----------------------+
| element with index 3  | <-- -4
+-----------------------+
| element with index 2  | <-- -5
+-----------------------+
| element with index 1  | <-- bottom ("relative" index -6 )
+-----------------------+
```

You could also say that the "normal index" (the one indexing from the bottom) is the absolute index of the element (like that of an array in C, besides starting from 1). Instead the negative index is "relative" to the top of stack.`lua_gettop` gives you the absolute index of the stack top (which has always relative index `-1`).

Why are there two ways of indexing the stack, then? Because sometimes it is useful to access the elements like an array (using an absolute index) and sometimes you only need to access the last pushed elements (so indexing from the top).

BTW, I usually visualize the Lua stack reversed: starting from above and growing downwards (i.e. the stack top is at the bottom of my mental representation). I find this mental model more useful because I interpret the index -1 as "*step back in code (upwards, therefore) until you find the the first push*". In this fashion, index -2 would be "*step back in code until you find the second push*", etc.. All this helps me quickly identify where I pushed what.

However, to avoid confusion, here I used a more classical representation, where the stack top is drawn really at the top!

Answer (score 6):

From PIL (http://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html)

> Notice that a negative index -x is equivalent to the positive index gettop - x + 1.

Therefore

```
if( lua_isfunction(L,lua_gettop(L)) ) {
```

does the same than

```
if( lua_isfunction(L,-1) ) {
```

Comment: Not when `lua_gettop` returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference if you immediately use it as an index like that. But you can do other things with it, like store the index and use it later, when it might no longer be the last index.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already stated, lua_gettop returns the index of the top element on the stack. If the stack is empty then there is no element on index -1. So the function lua_gettop gives you a boundary for the index you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you don't need to use lua_gettop in your example. You need it when you're going to push other things on top and want to reference the previous top.

Here's an example where we create a table with a value inside it:

```cpp
// Correct
lua_newtable(L);
const int table_idx = lua_gettop(L);
lua_pushinteger(L, volume);
lua_setfield(L, table_idx, "volume");
// We stored the index for our destination table. Can push all we want on the
// stack and always have an index for our table.


// Wrong
lua_newtable(L);
const int table_idx = -1;
lua_pushinteger(L, volume);
lua_setfield(L, table_idx, "volume");
// Fail. Top of the stack is now an integer.


// Wrong
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushinteger(L, volume);
lua_setfield(L, -1, "volume");
// Fail. Top of the stack is now an integer.


// Okay
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushinteger(L, volume);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "volume");
// Correct, but less robust.
```